# How do I charge a 4-cell Li-ion battery pack?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have a 4-cell Li-ion battery pack, purchased from RS Components (code: 144-9416).

Link :

https://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/blocs-batteries-rechargeables/1449416?cm_mmc=FR-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CFS_FR_FR_RS+PRO_PO4700199950-_-Batteries+%26+Chargeurs-_-1449416&matchtype=&pla-2205821052666&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiA3uGqBhDdARIsAFeJ5r1KOodY1cdB2WVZ8klYim8k7NhUbzdr9-YHQxhdF0BCcEC7UiSACCgaAo71EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

It integrates a BMS, as you can understand on the datasheet (and I feel the PCB too).

So my question is: **How can I recharge?**

- Do I have to design my own battery-charging PCB (with a IC from TI, for example)?
- Or can I just apply, let's say 24V, and the BMS will do the CC/CV up to 16.8V?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Good day to you all.

Answer (score 5):

> Do I have to design my own battery-charging PCB? Or can I just apply, let's say 24V?

Neither.

1. Buy a ready-made 4S Li-ion battery charger (14.8 V nominal, 16.8 V constant voltage, and no more than a 1.3 A constant current). [For example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08JPTQD9C).
2. Connect it to the battery through its BMS.

Comment: The linked charger is incompatible with OP's battery pack as it requires a balancer connection, which the pack in question doesn't have. The pack balances itself via its internal BMS and only requires external 16.8V CC/CV to be applied.

Comment: "The pack balances itself via its internal BMS". There's no BMS in that battery.

Comment: You're right... I managed to track down the exact PCM used: https://power.tenergy.com/protection-circuit-module-pcb-for-14-4v-14-8v-4s-li-ion-battery-packs-working-10a-cutoff-40a/ I really didn't expect RS to sell battery packs that literally can't be charged safely at all, so given that the pack doesn't have balancing leads, I expected it to balance internally. It's quite strange to me that RS would sell a product that's dangerous by design. I guess I'll have to delete my wrong answer.

Comment: @JonathanS. I was also trying to track down the circuit used. The RS datasheet shows a picture of a PCB with the label ``cl-s04-019-a01``. A search found the datasheet [S-8254A Series](https://www.ablic.com/en/doc/datasheet/battery_protection/S8254A_E.pdf) which doesn't mention cell balancing. Whereas [BQ29330](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq29330.pdf) is a datasheet for a different device which does mention cell balancing for S41P cells.

Comment: (cont)  Both the S8254A and BQ29330 datasheets show the cells connected in the same way, the difference being the BQ29330 has ``Cell balancing of each cell can be performed via a cell bypass path integrated into the bq29330``. Is that the key to look for to confirm if cell balancing is implemented?

Comment: It does have per-cell voltage monitoring - the pack **can be charged safely**. But it won't last as long as a pack with balancing, because eventually one of the cells will get out of sync and the protection circuit will cut off early.

Comment: Ok so this battery only integrates a PCM (Protection Circuit Module) which only manages UV/OV per cell, and not a BMS, which manages e.g. balancing.

For charging I simply propose :
- Using a generic 20V DC power supply, 1A max :
- The max current will be reached (1A), so the power supply will behave like a current source (1st phase of CC/CV).
- The circuit will be cut by the PCM at approximately 4.20V per cell.
- The battery will therefore only be charged to around 80%.

Comment: I don't see any electronic assembly in that battery. Does it have one on the back side, the side we can't see? If so: that board does have balancing.